# Find files newer than 15 seconds but older than 2 seconds

Tags: bash, find

I want to find files newer than 15 seconds but older than 2 seconds.
Here is the script I'm currently using that grabs files newer than 15 seconds:

```
find /my/directory -name '*.jpg' -not -newermt '-15 seconds'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What operating system are you using? There are differences in the `find` implementations.

Comment: Should a file modified exactly 2 seconds ago match?  What about a file modified exactly 15 seconds ago?

Comment: Newer than 2 seconds at the time the script start or at the time it ends?

Comment: @Mikel, that's probably irrelevant as clocks have nanosecond resolution nowadays.

Comment: Ok... since no one else is asking... @Yllier123 why do you need to find files created between 2 < x < 15 sec? I'm just curious.

Comment: @CBauer I have an Image cache that keeps pictures from the past 30 seconds. I needed to take pictures from the last 15 seconds of that image cache and Email them to myself. The script I wrote for doing this would sometimes grab a picture while it was being moved into the cache and register it as corrupted. By grabbing pictures that are two seconds old, there is no way it would grab a picture as it was being copied over.

Comment: @Yllier123 then you should fix your process so partial files cannot appear in the directory

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can combine multiple predicates by chaining them.

There's no `-oldermt`, but you can write that as `-not -newermt`.

You want:

- `-newermt '-15 seconds'` to say the file is less than 15 seconds old, and
- `-not -newermt '-2 seconds'` to say the file is more than 2 seconds old

Try:

```
find /my/directory -newermt '-15 seconds' -not -newermt '-2 seconds'
```

Or, to be POSIX compliant:

```
find /my/directory -newermt '-15 seconds' \! -newermt '-2 seconds'
```

Also, just so you (and other readers) are aware, "newer" means modified more recently than, not created more recently than.

Comment: Nice. Note that `-not -newermt '-2 seconds'` will also match files exactly 2 seconds old. Use `-not -newermt '3 seconds'` to exclude those as well.

Comment: Yeah, the edge cases are always fun.  I'm not actually sure what resolution it uses for these comparisions.  My assumption is that anything that's modified ~2.000000001 seconds ago is a match, but that would also depend on your file system and operating system.

Comment: Good point, I have no idea what the resolution is. I just tested with `touch -d "2 seconds ago" file; find . -newermt '-15 seconds' -not -newermt '-2 seconds'` and got `file`.

Comment: @terdon Well, that depends on whether the timestamps have a resolution more precise than one second; _that_ will depend on the system, the filesystem, and might even vary between files on the same filesystem if it's used by multiple different machines.

Comment: "newer" means "more recently than". It's the "m" that means "modified".

Comment: @OrangeDog, I was referring to "newer" in the question, not in the flag name.

Comment: @Mikel why is `-not` needed here and not needed in things like `find . -iname "*.avi" -size +50M` which will find all `avi` files larger than 50 MB? Here multiple conditions are combined together too.

Comment: @Alexander Cska There are three different Boolean operators: AND, OR, and NOT. They all combine terms but in different ways. In your example, the operator is AND, which happens by default in `find`.

Comment: @Mikel thank you for this very useful and helpful reply. Just to wrap it up, why the negation of the first command is needed  `-newermt '-15 seconds' -not`. This is clearly some mechanics of the logic, but still don't get it. `find ./   -newermt "2018-12-01" -not  -newermt "2018-12-14"`  works with and without the `-not`. If anything my naive guess would be a logical `-and` here. if Newer than AND older than ...

Answer (score 5):

You did not mention your OS....

This works fine with a modern find implementation like the one from FreeBSD or with `sfind`.

`find /my/directory -name '*.jpg' -mtime -15s -mtime +2s`

Sfind is part of the Schily tools: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

WARNING: I just discovered a problem in `sfind`. If the `-mtime` arguments are less than 60s, it will not work correctly as the file times are currently compared with a time stamp 60 seconds in the future that was originally computed for the year switch for `-ls`.

BTW: `-not` does not belong to `find`, it is a non-portable GNUism.

Comment: There is the ```bash``` tag… So the environment could be Cygwin, Debian GNU/Hurd, ```bash``` running on FreeBSD or Solaris, … ;-)

Comment: For GNU `find`, it seems that decimals, although crazy, can be used as a workaround.

Comment: POSIX find [does have `!` for -not as `!  expression`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47). So, no big deal.

Comment: @phk This is why I mentioned the method that works with an enhanced standard `primary` from `find` to inform people that there is no need to always add new `primaries` to find to be able to enhance functionality. BTW: A fixed `libfind` has been published in the `schily tools`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra the problem is that `gfind` did add the `-not` alias at all. It was never needed and it's presence can be seen as a vendor lock in strategy.